# HTML - Scrolling inner box when it reaches a specific size

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a bit of a puzzling piece of HTML I have to write.

I need to have an inner box that when reaches a specific size it allows for its content to be displayed with an horizontal scroll.

I have attached a pretty detailed schema which I hope to be clear enough. 
[image: layout schema]

I have tried few approaches which resulted in utmost disaster so I would appreciate any help. Preferably just css/html no javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://codepen.io/dherran/pen/KzEdZZ

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    +
  </div>
</div>
```